# How to have a method return a float with multiple parameters in xcode?

Tags: xcode, methods, parameters, return

I know there have been questions asked on this topic but they all differ slightly
what I want is a simple method that you pass an x value a y value and a quadrant value and it returns angle so far I have...

```
-(float)getAngle: (float)x  yvalue:(float)y Quadrant:(float) quadrant{

float angle=0.0;
 if(quadrant==1){

  }

  NSLog(@"%f",x);
 return angle;
}
```

im not concerned about calculations at this point. I just want to know how to properly declare this method, because it wont let me name the first parameter.

Comment: if i try to give the (float)x paramater a name it says

Comment: xavlue used as the name of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selector

Comment: What do you mean "*if* i try..."  The first parameter is designated by "getAngle" and it's "dummy" inside your method is "x".  It doesn't need any other names.

Comment: The method's name is valid but poorly chosen. In particular the `getAngle:` is misleading. It's not an angle you provide for that argument but the x value. Thus it should rather be named something akin to `- (float)getAngleForX:(float)x y:(float)y quadrant:(float)quadrant`. I also changed the `Quadrant:` to `quadrant:` as method argument labels (the text before `:(float)quadrant`) are expected to start with a lowercase character.

Comment: ok thanks, I was getting confused between method name and parameter placement, this clarified it for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, as is, would work fine.  Suppose you have a method like what you posted:

```
-(float)getAngle: (float)x  yvalue:(float)y Quadrant:(float) quadrant{

    float angle=0.0;
    if(quadrant==1){

    }

    NSLog(@"%f",x);
    return angle;
}
```

You could call this within the current class, and receive the returned value, like so:

```
// sample values added
float result = [self getAngle:-1.0 yvalue:0.5 Quadrant:2.0];
NSLog(@"%f",result);
```

Comment: ok, so what I can understand is that if i kept it this way the first parameter would be named "getAngle"?

Comment: @user1422132 - Essentially.  The entire method is named "getAngle:yvalue:Quadrant:".

Comment: Inside of the method, the first parameter is named "x" since you have ":(float)x" inside of the method declaration.  You call the method by writing "getAngle:" and your input, then doing the same for yvalue and quadrant).